# Angular modal error: ariaLabelledBy does not exist in NgbModalOptions

Tags: angular

I NEW to angular. I need to add a popup(modal) to my angular component. So I use this code as my component ts code.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


    import { BookService } from '../../shared/book.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-book',
      templateUrl: './book.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./book.component.css'],
      providers:[BookService]
    })
    export class BookComponent implements OnInit {
      book$ : object;
      closeResult: string;

      constructor(private bookService: BookService,
                  private modalService: NgbModal) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe(
          BookService => this.book$ = BookService
        )
      }
      open(content) {
        this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
          this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        }, (reason) => {
          this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        });
      }
      private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
        if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
          return 'by pressing ESC';
        } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
          return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
        } else {
          return  `with: ${reason}`;
        }
      }
}
```

And this is my html code I used to load the modal.

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button">
              <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Save click')">Save</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>
<hr>

<pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>
```

So I got a error in my component ts file.
This is the line I got error.

```
this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
```

I got this error. [image]

I search for this error every where. But I did not find a solution. I need a modal to work as a details updating form. Thank you very much if you can give me a solution.

Comment: can you post your  `ngmodal` npm version?

Comment: 6.1.0 is my npm version

Comment: I meant `ng-bootstrap` version

Comment: If you use  `latest` or from `2.2` it should work, for your reference https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.ts#L13

Comment: npm package 2.2.0 , Bootstrap 4 version

Comment: try to remove node_modules then npm install

Comment: sorry can you explain what will happen when we remove node_modules.

Comment: i checked with angular 6, it is working fine in my case. When you remove `node_modules`, you will fresh install npm packets.

Comment: I also using angular 6 okay I will check it thank you so I don't need to do any changes in my this code?

Comment: thank you it works